# Call a rest API in react native at scheduled intervals

Tags: android, react-native

Here is the requirement I have received:

> I would like my Android app to make a rest API call at specified
> durations of the day. I don't expect the app to be alive (either
> foreground or background) during these periods.  After the API calls I
> would like to send a notifications to the user with the retrieved
> data.  In simpler terms, for example at 10am every day the user gets
> notified with data retrieved via a rest API.

How can I achieve this in react native.
This is similar to what task schedulers can achieve in Windows. I am trying to stay away from push notifications which would be the last resort.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt would be to use [react-native-background-fetch](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch) which seems to work even after termination for android to fetch the data and combine it with local push notifications from [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) to present the data.

Comment: This will not work. See comment from Christocracy in the link https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch/issues/162